# how to create promises properly in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, promise, visual-studio-code

I'm working currently on a project and I need to make some functions asynchronously.

I searched for that, and I found that promises will do the work. Here is my code:

```
var check = `SELECT * FROM change_name_spelling WHERE SID = ${SID}`;
isSIDInDB = false;

let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    con.query(check, function callback(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('length: ' + result.length);

        const error = false;

        if (!error) resolve(result.length);
        else reject('Rejected');

    });

    promise1
        .then(function(value) {
            if (value > 0) {
                isSIDInDB = true;
                console.log('is db, from query, ' + isSIDInDB);
            } else {
                isSIDInDB = false;
                console.log('is Not in db, from query, ' + isSIDInDB);
            }
            resolve(isSIDInDB);
            reject();
        })
        .then(function(value) {
            if (value) {
                console.log('in db');
            } else {
                console.log('not in db');
            }
        });
}).catch(error, function() {
    console.log(error);
});
```

However, when I run this code, I got these errors:

1- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: promise1 is not defined.

2- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

3- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: error is not defined.

please note that I already installed the promise packages in VS code using the command "npm install Promise" but still got the same errors. What shall I do?

Comment: inside a `.then` method of promise you **do not** resiolve nor reject. You simply return whatever you need to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You have `promise1.then(...)` in the body of the callback function that is part of `promise1` definition, which is why you get `ReferenceError`. Basically, you're trying to refer to `promise1` as you are initializing the variable. Move `promise1.then(...)` outside of the callback function.

2.
You have `resolve` and `reject` right after each other on this piece of code here:

```
resolve(isSIDInDB);
reject();
```

This `reject` will never be called since `resolve` is always called first.

3.
You need to pass the `error` variable to the callback function.

```
#This is wrong
}).catch(error, function() {
    console.log(error);
});

#This is right
}).catch( function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Start by fixing this and see what errors remain.

Also, you might want to read up on promises to understand them better:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `promise1` object in the promise constructor function itself. That is the reason for `promise1` is not defined error.
Also as mentioned in one of the comments, you shouldn't be using the resolve or reject function inside the `then` function. Those functions won't even be available once you have correctly created the `promise1` object

Please change the code to as below and try once.

```
var check = `SELECT * FROM change_name_spelling WHERE SID = ${SID}`;
isSIDInDB = false;

let promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  con.query(check, function callback(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('length: ' + result.length);

    const error = false;

    if (!error) resolve(result.length);
    else reject('Rejected');
  })
});

promise1.then(function (value) {
  if (value > 0) {
    isSIDInDB = true;
    console.log('is db, from query, ' + isSIDInDB);
  } else {
    isSIDInDB = false;
    console.log('is Not in db, from query, ' + isSIDInDB);
  }
  if (isSIDInDB)
    return isSIDInDB;
  throw new Error(`not found`);
})
  .then(function (value) {
    if (value) {
      console.log('in db');
    } else {
      console.log('not in db');
    }
  }).catch(error, function () {
    console.log(error);
  });
```